# How to update a Glip chatbot's name or avatar icon after it's been added to a team?

Tags: icons, bots, ringcentral, glip

I have created and added my `Glip` bot to my Glip team, during which time the icon and name was chosen.

In Glip, I can change my own icon and name by clicking on the profile, but I cannot modify the bot's profile.

I was wondering if I can update the icon or the bot name after it's been added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both the bot name and bot icon in Glip can be updated via the Update Extension API using the bot's access token if the bot app has the `EditExtensions` permission.

**Update Bot Name via Update Extension API**

The Update Extension Info API can be used by the bot to update the bot's name in Glip if the bot has the `EditExtensions` app permission. The bot's name in Glip will be updated to reflect this in real-time.

This is an example HTTP request.

```
PUT /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~
Authorization: Bearer <botAccessToken>
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "contact": {
    "firstName": "Mr.",
    "lastName": "Bot"
  }
}
```

More info is available here:

API Reference: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefGetExtensionInfo

**Update Bot Icon via Upload User Profile Image API**

The bot icon in Glip can be updated using the Upload User Profile Image API, which also requires the `EditExtensions` application permission. Like the bot name, the bot icon will be updated in Glip in real-time.

Here is a sample request.

```
POST /restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/profile-image
Authorization: Bearer <botAccessToken>
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;boundary=Boundary_1234567890

--Boundary_1234567890
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="icon.jpg"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: image/jpeg

JVBERi0xLjMKJcTl8uXrp/Og0MTGCjQgMCBvYmoKPDwgL0xlbmd0aCA1IDAg
[...]
ZWYKMjQ0MjcKJSVFT0YK

--Boundary_1234567890--
```

Here is an example using curl. Of note, it's necessary to explicitly state the file content type, e.g. `type=image/jpeg` below.

```
$ curl -v -H "Authorization: Bearer <botAccessToken>" \
-F "image=@bot_icon.jpg;type=image/jpeg" \
"https://platform.ringcentral.com/restapi/v1.0/account/~/extension/~/profile-image"
```

More info is available on this API here:

API Reference: https://developers.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefCreateExtensionProfileImage